# How to caught exception when django query is not performed due to no internet connection

Tags: python, django, database, exception, django-rest-framework

I need to handle the scenario when django query can't reach the database due to no internet connection

I tried with try-except block like this, but there's no exception caugth:

```py
class SomeManager(models.Manager):
    def some_query(self):
       try:
           return self.filter(my_model_id=<some int number>)
       except Exception as e:
           logger.error(e)
```

How can i handle this?

Comment: Is there code before that section?

Comment: No, that is all the code that i'm testing. @101

Comment: There must be more code, `self` only makes sense in the context of more code around it.

Comment: I already edit the code in the post. Please take a look @101